# Grafana - Graph - can 1 Graph line have more than 1 color?

Tags: grafana

Can 1 Graph line have more than 1 color?

An example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it cannot because a line is plotted based on a query. An alternative would be to add an alert that sets a threshold.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you!